# Why does this For loop crash the browser lab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably a dumb question, but why is this simple loop crashing?

**HTML:**

`<p></p>`

**JS:**

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

for(var x = 0; x = array.length; x++) {
        $("p").html(array[x]);
}
```

Example Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fnpcfuzf/).

Comment: Because your loop never stops, you are doing x = array.length instead of x == array.length. And even then, it should be x == array.length -1

Comment: Or `x < array.length` as you probably intended given the loop's contents.

Comment: You're not crashing the browser, simply hanging it with an infinite loop.

Comment: As you've all proved, I've forgotten how to do loops. All hope is lost.

Comment: @juvian Your second statement is wrong. That would only be true on the very last iteration.

Comment: @4castle my bad, meant <=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `x = array.length` is not a "*real*" condition, and equality doesn't make sense in iteration anyway.

Try this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        $("p").html(array[x]);
}
```

Comment: It might make sense if you did `x != array.length`, but don't do that.

Comment: @4castle that's **in**equality.

Comment: You should mention that the reason it's looping infinitely is because `4` is a truthy value. `x = array.length` assigns but also returns `4`.

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 errors:

1st you don't test the condition. `x = array.length;` is an *attribution* not a comparison. You are atributting array.length to x instead of comparing them. The corret comparison statement would be:

```
x == array.length;
```

and 2nd, even if it were a comparasion it would exceed array length because array index it's zero-based.

so the correct would be:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        $("p").html(array[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Long your array has keys your condition will be true, like a while loop.

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        $("p").html(array[x]);
}
```

This will stop on the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is based on x, which is initialized with 0.

Your loop condition is evaluated by executing:

```
x = array.length
```

That returns the value of x, not equal to 0, '', false, undefined or null so this condition will always be positive.

The loop continues to iterate, over and over again, always assigning x the same value, which does an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try `x < array.length` instead of `x = array.length`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is better suited as a comment, but in this case that comment was already made.